# Temporary C strings have same address

Tags: c, gdb

These two lines produce the following output in `gdb`. Note that the addresses of the two temporary strings, `first_str` and `second_str` have the same address. Why is that?

```
char *first_str = inet_ntoa(first->dest);
char *second_str = inet_ntoa(second->dest);


(gdb) p first_str
$3 = 0x7ffff7ff06d8 "54.208.71.98"
(gdb) p second_str
$4 = 0x7ffff7ff06d8 "54.208.71.98"
```

`first->dest` and `second->dest` contain different values.

Comment: That's because these functions are not reentrant, inet_ntoa uses a static or global internal buffer. You should be using inet_ntop.

Comment: did `inet_ntoa` promise not to do that? Maybe you'll have to work around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

inet_ntoa uses a static buffer for its implementation, so essentially each call is writing the ascii ip address to the same place. See below:

https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/net.subproj/inet_ntoa.c

```
char *
inet_ntoa(in)
    struct in_addr in;
{
    static char b[18];
    register char *p;

    p = (char *)&in;
#define UC(b)   (((int)b)&0xff)
    (void)snprintf(b, sizeof(b),
        "%d.%d.%d.%d", UC(p[0]), UC(p[1]), UC(p[2]), UC(p[3]));
    return (b);
}
```

You should be using [inet_ntop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_pton.html).

inet_ntop also has the added benefit of supporting IPv6, which any newly written code really should be looking to support.

Usage of inet_ntop:

```
char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr.sin_addr, ip, sizeof(ip))) {
    /// do something with error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `inet_ntoa` [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

"The application should not make any assumptions about the way in which the memory is allocated. The string returned is guaranteed to be valid only until the next Windows Sockets function call is made within the same thread."

It appears that it just uses a static buffer. So you need to copy the result to a new buffer before the next call.