# why 2 different strings have the same address in C?

Tags: c, local-variables

Code and example csv file below.

The Program I write is a csv reader. In the while loop I acquire the line of the file as a string and then with sscanf I extract the data that I store in local variables.

I have 2 strings that I store in char* name and char* surname but they happen to have the same address :

```
Printing description of name:
(char *) name = 0x000000010004da78 "Bob"
Printing description of surname:
(char *) surname = 0x000000010004da78 "Bob
```

I don't understand why since they have different variable names.

I hoped to have an answer with that question but it wasn't my problem : [Temporary C strings have same address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087080/temporary-c-strings-have-same-address)

I renamed the variables and re-build the .exe (using Xcode) but the problem remains. Any idea why that problem happens ?

Thanks

Code

```
void readFileTest(FILE* *pFile, TTest* *pRootTest)
//Reads the content of the file, line by line
{
    int count=0;
    char string[MAX_SIZE];
    TTest *pTestCurrent=NULL, *pPrevious=NULL;

    //Reads first line (wich is the label line)
    fgets(string, MAX_SIZE, *pFile);
    printf("Column labelling : %s\n", string);

    //allocating pointer
    pTestCurrent=malloc(sizeof(TTest));
    pTestCurrent->ID=0;
    pTestCurrent->name="";
    pTestCurrent->surname="";
    pTestCurrent->mean=0.0;
    pTestCurrent->pNext=NULL;
    pTestCurrent->pPrevious=NULL;

    (*pRootTest)=pTestCurrent;
    pPrevious=pTestCurrent;

    //Extracts data of each line and stores it in a node
    while(fgets(string, MAX_SIZE, *pFile)) //reads line by line until the EOF
    {
         int identification=0;
         char* name;
         char* surname;
         float mean=0.0;

         //Counts iterations (lines) in the file
         count+=1;
         printf("Iteration n°%d\n", count);

         //Extracts data of the line in variables
         sscanf(string, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%f", &identification, name, surname, &mean);

        //Assign data in variables to node in pTestCurrent
         pTestCurrent->ID=identification;
         pTestCurrent->name=name;
         pTestCurrent->surname=surname;
         pTestCurrent->mean=mean;

         //Displays data in node
         printf("Line content (stored in pTestCurrent) :\nID : %d\nNAME : %s\nSURNAME : %s\nMEAN : %f\n\n", pTestCurrent->ID, pTestCurrent->name, pTestCurrent->surname, pTestCurrent->mean);

         if(pTestCurrent==NULL)
         {
             printf("ERROR : pointer pTestCurrent is NULL, the programm will exit now\n");
             EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

         //Refresh pointer
         pTestCurrent->pNext=malloc(sizeof(TTest));
         pTestCurrent=pTestCurrent->pNext;
         pTestCurrent->pPrevious=pPrevious;
         pTestCurrent->pNext=NULL;
         pPrevious=pTestCurrent;
         }
};
```

Example file :

```
ID,NAME,SURNAME,MEAN
1,Smith,Bob,4.32
2,Mason,Jack,9.21
3,Gabe,John,2.67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make two mistakes:

1. you do not have valid memory when you `sscanf`
2. you do not copy the values scanned.

The first:

```
    sscanf(string, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%f", &identification, name, surname, &mean);
```

here `name` and `surname` are only pointers to char, but they do not point to memory of your program (they are uninitalized and can point anywhere. It would have been likely you got a segmentation fault). In stead, do:

```
    char name[64], surname[64];  // or any proper size for the names
```

You now have valid memory for your `sscanf`.

Second, when you copy the data scanned to your structure, you must have allocated memory in your structure for the data. With only `pTestCurrent->name=name;` you place the *pointer* to `name` in the name field of your structure, but you do not copy the data. Consequently, upon your next `sscanf` you will just overwrite the data. In stead, do:

```
    pTestCurrent->name= malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(pTestCurrent->name, name);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, inside the `while` loop, you're using uninitialized pointer. Those pointers are not guaranteed to point anywhere *valid*, and you're trying to access the memory location pointer by them. This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Solution: before you pass them as the argument to `sscanf()`, you need to make sure they point to some valid memory which can be accessed by your process.

Comment: It is even worse as there is no memory allocated but accessed. It is just poor knowledge of the the basics of the C language.

Comment: Initializing them won't help if he continues to "copy" strings this way.